# Why are there multiple deserializers in kafka like string,byte, short?

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, streaming

```
val consumer: KafkaConsumer[Bytes, Bytes] = kafkaConsumer(config,new BytesDeserializer,new BytesDeserializer)
consumer.subscribe(util.Arrays.asList("fruits"))
while (true){
  val incoming = consumer.poll(1000)
  incoming.asScala.foreach(x=>println(x.value()))
}
```

Also using string deserializer gives the same output

```
val consumer: KafkaConsumer[String, String] = kafkaConsumer(config,new StringDeserializer,new StringDeserializer)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your particular case it depends on the way that String was encoded.

For example:

```
scala> val testStr = "TestStringą"
testStr: String = TestStringą
scala> testStr.getBytes("ISO-8859-2")
res6: Array[Byte] = Array(84, 101, 115, 116, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, -79)
scala> testStr.getBytes("UTF-8")
res7: Array[Byte] = Array(84, 101, 115, 116, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, -60, -123)
scala> testStr.getBytes("UTF-16")
res8: Array[Byte] = Array(-2, -1, 0, 84, 0, 101, 0, 115, 0, 116, 0, 83, 0, 116, 0, 114, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 103, 1, 5)
```

How you can see, depends on charset encoding binary representation is different.

`StringDeserializer` uses `UTF-8`, so if your String was encoded with `UTF-16` and send to Kafka topic, `StringDeserializer` will decode it as:

```
scala> val v = new String(res8, "UTF-8")
v: String = ��?T?e?s?t?S?t?r?i?n?g??
```

It is not what you would like to have.

You have to remember to use compatible Deserializer and Serializer.
Each Deserializer/Serializer is dedicated for particular type - String, Long, Short Bytes, Custom etc.
Each of those types is represented differently - ex. has different length, encoding etc.